# The Refractive Index of Water after Several Heating and Cooling Cycles

Tags: temperature, water, refraction

If the refractive index of water under a certain temperature, say 20 degreeC, is 1.33334. Will it return to exact the same value after one or several heating and cooling cycles? Or will it shift a little bit to some certain direction (higher or lower than 1.33334)?

Comment: Depends on how pure the water is, perhaps. If you heat it for long enough in an open container, then the final value will end up much closer to 1...

Comment: Sorry @JonCuster, I cannot catch your idea. Do you mean all the liquid water are vaporized? So, if the water are not completely vaporized. I simply heat 1 L water from 20 degreeC (refractive index = 1.33334) to 90 degreeC, and then cool down to 20 degreeC for several cycles. Will the refractive index perfectly go back to 1.33334 every time when the temperature is 20 degreeC? Thanks!

Comment: If you have pure liquid water, a thermodynamically stable phase, why do you suppose that any path through phase space, returning to the same point, will affect the material properties?

Comment: That's because I performed the heating and cooling cycle and finally obtained the relationship between temperature and refractive index. I detected large amount of refractive index change after one cycle but sometimes not. I wonder if this change is caused by the environment, the sensor, or water itself. @JonCuster

Comment: fengfeng, can you really measure the refractive index of water to 5-decimal accuracy? what is the repeatability of your measurement tool? How many measurements did you take for each data point?

Comment: Hi @nielsnielsen, the accuracy of my sensor is about 0.0000125 RIU, and it can be higher. If you want high sensitivity refractive index sensor, try fiber optical sensors. Because my sensor was damaged, I only tested 3 times. More tests will be applied after I make another sensor.